# Customized Control [Label], how to add attribute

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using customized controls for html with vb.net for code behind. The custom control[Label] doesn't have [FOR] attribute. Now I have to add that attribute that [Label] Control. May I ask how to do this?
P.S. I'm not the one who did the customization, it's given to me that way. And I have no idea at all how to do customization on controls.
Thank you!

html:

```
     <custom:custom_label runat="server" id="lblAgreement">
```

code behind:

```
     lblAgreement.Attributes.Add("For", ???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to simple create in the code behind a public method (getter/setter) that thus returns, or sets the desired value or attribute against the control(s) in that user control.

So, say I have a user control with a label, and a text box.

So, my markup is this:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server" Text=""
        For="" >
    </asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

So, now what does the user control code look like to set the text box, or the label text value, or the label For value?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


Public Property Text As String
    Get
        Return Me.txt1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.txt1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property LableText As String
    Get
        Return Me.Lbl1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.Lbl1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property ForV As String
    Get
        Return Me.Lbl1.Attributes("For").ToString
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.Lbl1.Attributes.Add("For", value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Now, as a habit in vb.net, I in MOST cases will simply use a public variable of the given class and NOT bother with a get/set pair in the code. And in 99% of use cases, you do not need to waste your time writing get/set, but can simply have a public member of the class.

Hence:

```
 Public FirstName as string
```

HOWEVER, and this is a BIG WHOPPER however, one exception to above is when building user controls in vb. If you want the above values to work in markup, or even show in the property sheet?

Then you want to use public properties, and also use get/set for that property.

Doing the above results in a VERY nice property sheet when the user control is dropped into a standard webforms page.

You can then either use the property sheet to set values of the user control, or you can type out the values in the markup, and you even have inteli-sense to help you.

Thus this:

[image]

So, note how we can use either the markup or the property sheet for this custom control. (and any public property with a get/set will of course show up in the property sheet).

And if you want to expose a control property such as text, then create a public get/set that sets the value of the given control. So, in above, I want a public text setting for the text box, and thus:

```
Public Property Text As String
    Get
        Return Me.txt1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.txt1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

So, in code behind, I can go

```
MyUserControl.Text = "Hello"
```

And the above will set the txt value of the text box.

You can also use markup with the above, and again markup will work, and set the value of the control in question.

So, simple create public methods of the user control for properties of the control(s) in that user control you want public exposed to the web page.

Last but not least?

The keyword "For" looks to be a reserved word in VB, and thus I used ForV.

I suspect that the issue is not setting the For attribute in code, but in fact setting the value to some other control that exists in the same user control.

Your question has not asked about this issue and challenge. Since multiple copies of a given control can be freely used  in a given webforms page, then if the For attribute is to point to say a textbox inside of the same user control?

Then I suggest the following code to set the For attribute to the current generated client id of the textbox be used:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.ForV = Me.txt1.ClientID

End Sub
```

Note that an asp.net label control is rendered as a span element, and thus really does not have a valid "For" markup tag anyway.

This does suggest that using a HTML label tag with a runat="server" and a id tag is required if you need an HTML label element to be rendered by the user control. Using an asp.net label element results in output rendered as an span element and not an valid label element (which does not have a For tag anyway).